# What is the bin/app folder in Symfony 2.8?

Tags: symfony

I have just updated my Symfony 2.7 project to 2.8. No I noticed that there is a new folder `bin/app` which has not been there before the update. The `bin` has always been part of the project, but not `bin/app`. The folder seems to be an exact copy of the existing `app` folder.

I know that Symfony 3.0 introduced a new folder structure and that some parts (e.g. app/console) have been moved to `bin/`, but I am not aware of changed folders in Symfony 2.8.

Why is there a copy of the `app/` folder and what is its purpose?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't make a copy by an accident? Folder structure **is not** part of the framework, but application skeleton (Symfony Standard Edition). The whole Symfony Framework sits inside `vendor` folder.

Comment: There is no bin/app folder in Symfony 2.8.11 skeleton.